# KeyError: 'print $2' when I use subprocess.call("ps -ef | grep wget | grep {0} | awk '{print $2}'

Tags: python, bash, operating-system

In my macOS, I using a wget downloading the [www.test.com](http://www.test.com) index page.

then I have below python code:

```
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import subprocess

url = "https://www.test.com"

subprocess.call("ps -ef | grep wget | grep {0}  | awk '{print $2}'".format(url), shell=True)
```

when I run it, I get issue:

```
subprocess.call("ps -ef | grep wget | grep {0}  | awk '{print $2}'".format(url), shell=True)
KeyError: 'print $2'
```

and I switch the `subprocess.call()` to `os.system()`, still get this issue.

Comment: Try escaping the single quotes before and after { print $2 }

Comment: escaping the single quotes changes nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is not caused by subprocess, rather the string format.

```
"ps -ef | grep wget | grep {0}  | awk '{print $2}'".format(url)
```

you can use `%s` to forming string.

```
"ps -ef | grep wget | grep %s  | awk '{print $2}'"%(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `subprocess.run()`

From [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)

> Code needing to capture stdout or stderr should use run() instead

> **Note** : Do not use **stdout=PIPE** or **stderr=PIPE** with this function. The child process will block if it generates enough output to a pipe to fill up the OS pipe buffer as the pipes are not being read from.